# Не переведено "This user hasn't posted yet" на странице профиля участника

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника

Например, на странице этого профиля: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/309438/user309438

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ключ в трансе:  `3f6301f20c87eb9ee9aa2d2e591af2c7`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выкатили перевод:

> У этого участника пока нет сообщений.